# Scenarios for Docker daemon and client / CLI on separate boxes?

Tags: docker

What would be some use case for keeping Docker clients or CLI and Docker daemon on separate machines?

Why would you keep the two separate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *never* run the two separately.  The only exception is with very heavily managed `docker-machine` setups where you're confident that Docker has set up all of the required security controls.  Even then, I'd only use that for a local VM when necessary (as part of Docker Toolbox; to demonstrate a Swarm setup) and use more purpose-built tools to provision cloud resources.

Consider this Docker command:

```
docker run --rm -v /:/host busybox vi /host/etc/shadow
```

Anyone who can run this command can change any *host* user's password to anything of their choosing, and easily take over the whole system.  There are probably more direct ways to root the host.  The only requirement to run this command is that you have access and permissions to access the Docker socket.

This means: **anyone who can access the Docker socket can trivially root the host**.  If it's network accessible, anyone who can reach port 2375 on your system can take it over.

This isn't an acceptable security position for the mild convenience of not needing to `ssh` to a remote server to run `docker` commands.  The various common system-automation tools (Ansible, Chef, Salt Stack) all can invoke Docker as required, and using one of these tools is almost certainly preferable to trying to configure TLS for Docker.

If you run into a tutorial or other setup advising you to start the Docker daemon with a `-H` option to publish the Docker socket over the network (even just to the local system) be aware that it's a massive security vulnerability, equivalent to disabling your root password.

(I hinted above that [it's possible to use TLS encryption on the network socket](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/).  This is a tricky setup, and it involves sharing around a TLS client certificate that has root-equivalent power over the host.  I wouldn't recommend trying it; `ssh` to the target system or use an automation tool to manage it instead.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer an stressing the security implications. I came across this question whilst going through a tutorial and it made me wonder why you'd ever want to have the client and daemon on separate boxes.